# Why bluetoothctl is scanning but not displaying Bluetooth Low Energy devices?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, command-line-interface, bluez

I ran button & and bluetoothctl. In bluetoothctl gave commands set-scan-filter-clear, set-scan-filter-transport le, scan on. It is scanning BLE advertisement reports but not displaying under bluetoothctl. May I know the reason for this?

Comment: How do you know that it is scanning for BLE advert reports? What is the output of the command "btmgmt info" and "bluetoothctl --version"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting the bluetooth service in experimental mode?
You can check by running `service bluetooth status` and checking the command at the key `CGroup` (example pictures and more instructions (here)[https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation#setup-bluez-service-1701163-24])